# Нужны ли десь кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

«Без штанов», но при компьютере. (Имеется ввиду нищий, по аналогии с «гол как сокол»)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Все зависит от избитости, от степени распространённости того или иного выражения. Обычно в кавычки заключаются малоизвестные выражения, чтобы указать на необычность, образность того или иного выражения.

В вашем случае фразеологизм "Без штанов" уже зафиксирован в фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка.  Поэтому кавычки в вашем примере не нужны.

Comment: "Без штанов" само по себе не является фразеологизмом.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, кавычки здесь совершенно излишни. Здесь обыгрывается общеизвестное "без штанов, но в шляпе", так что отдельно "без штанов" закавычивать нет резона. Если уж кавычки использовать, то для всего выражения в целом, включая "компьютер", тогда это подчеркивало бы, что фраза изменена. Но здесь и в таком приеме нет никакой необходимости. Все достаточно прозрачно.

Comment: Это именно фразеологизм. Именно в этом виде зафиксирован в словаре фразеологизмов. Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.

Comment: ***Без штанов, а в шляпе
     — шутл. о странном (чаще странно, несуразно одетом) человеке.***

Словарь русского арго. — ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. С. Елистратов. 2002.

Comment: ***Без штанов (порток), но в шляпе***
    Говорится в адрес человека без вкуса, не умеющего красиво, гармонично одеваться. Также и в случае, когда кто-то приобретает слишком дорогую вещь, не имея порой самого необходимого.

***Жгучий глагол: Словарь народной фразеологии. — Зеленый век. В. Кузмич. 2000.****

Comment: ***Без штанов***
    Прост. Экспрес. ***Без средств, без самого необходимого (жить, остаться и т. п.). ****
***Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.***